# Displaying Datafield from mySQL in WP Shortcode

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to display field data in the WP front end using shortcodes from a new table.

[See Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URiPo.png)

After coming across many sources and research, I do not seem to find a simple way to display data in text (not table), contained within a specific field selected in the SQL query by means of SELECT FROM WHERE.

So far I called wpdb, selected the field, created a loop and echoed. But no results are displayed.
I also tried using print_r and implode but both failed too.

```
<?php
function Initial_Brief(){ global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT 'Initial_Brief'* FROM `Portal_100` WHERE Project_Title = 'Project 1'");
        foreach ($results as $result)
        echo $result['results'];
}
add_shortcode('Initial_Brief','Initial_Brief')
?>
```

Many thanks in advance,

To share the logic of this, which I find quite powerful, is to use shortcodes for displaying all text on the website, enabling text edit from the front-end by creating an HTML form which updates the specific field. I will create an edit icon displayed on hover to an editor's role, clicked to trigger a popup with an html form which calls a function to update the specific field in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some iterations I finally got it to work!

I understand mySQL does not accept input with a spacing? 
How can I insert a WHERE condition for multiple words or a paragraph?

It worked for me using the following script but I had to change the WHERE value into an integer.

```
<?php
add_shortcode('Initial_Brief', function(){
global $wpdb;
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("Select Value from `P100` WHERE `P100`.`id` = 1 ");
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql , ARRAY_A );
foreach ($results as $result) {
$display = implode(", ", $result);
echo $display;
});?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to call the [get_results](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/) method like this:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$id = 23;
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id= %d",$id);
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql , ARRAY_A );
?>
```

The use of the [prepare](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) method is a good practice for preparing a SQL query for safe execution (eg. preempt SQL injection), but it is no yet the execution, it returns a sanitized query string, if there is a query to prepare. 
It is also  good companion for the [query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/query/) method.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, but I don't think that is the main issue, I was using get_results but it still does not echo the data from the table.

I now have developed the following:
<?php
function Initial_Brief(){ global $wpdb;
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT 'Initial_Brief'* FROM `Portal_100` WHERE Project_Title = Project 1");
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql , ARRAY_A );
echo '<p>';
foreach ($results as $result) {
   $display = implode(", ", $result);
   echo $display;
}
echo '</p>';
}
add_shortcode('Initial_Brief','Initial_Brief')
?>

Still not working...

Comment: When you write `SELECT 'Initial_Brief'* FROM`... had you used this syntax before? I'm not used to this asterisk (*) in that position. Perhaps a missing dot in the middle? like `'Initial_Brief'.*`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seemed like mySQL does not accept a sentence in the WHERE input. Hence, can not put a where value for an address. (for example).

In other words I understand, and may be wrong, that we can only selectspecific fields using preassigned Unique or Primary keys?